# Google fusion tables gives me a 401 on 'show tables' query

Tags: php, sql, google-fusion-tables, http-status-code-401

I'm merely trying to 'SHOW TABLES' and I've tried to add the api key, the client id and secret and whatnot in the request URI and all i keep getting is
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"

It works fine with any other SQL query except for this one.. why is that?

How do I go about querying the right way here..?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to authenticate yourself using OAuth, depending on your setting you can let your users authenticate via Google, then you get a token that you can use to access the users Fusion Tables, or you create a so called [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) to access your application specific table.

See the [OAuth guide from Google](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/articles/oauthfusiontables), you could use the [PHP client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2) to handle the OAuth authentication.